# Transform Gravity Form Entry Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a drop down field that contain a letter than a description of the item:

```
A - New Return
B - Damaged Return
C - Warranty Return
```

I am trying to have the notification just show the first letter ie "A", any one know how?

Comment: you mean email notifications?

Comment: I guess the email notification isn't that important, I have the field entered into a spreadsheet using Zapier, that is the important peice.